# Laravel URL with optional parameter at the beginning

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm trying to get an URL with route binding as one statement in `routes/web.php` matching the following pattern:

- /abc/my-slug
- /de/abc/my-slug
- /es/abc/my-slug
- etc.

Notably, the first parameter is optional should default to "en". Is it possible to have route binding to load a model from two parameters with one statement instead of two in the routes file?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe (untested) ?

```
 Route::name('page')
      ->get('/{lang?}/{slug}', [Controller::class, 'index'])
      ->setDefaults(['lang' => 'en']);
```

Or as an alternative [read this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#default-values) on how to set defaults in a middleware

Comment: I've tried this, it's leading either to "missing parameter" as the default doesn't seem to get set or to `Required parameter $url_segment follows optional parameter $language` if I set the optional parameter as default in the controller method.

Comment: And if you also set the slug as optional ?

Comment: The it would match other routes too. I've opted to have multiple route as I couldn't figure it without.